# mv controller Route attribute is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have mvc controller named `MyCtl`.`MyController` contains two methods:

1. Test1
2. Test2

in my web api config I have

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );
```

*MyCtl.cs*:

```
        public class MyCtlController : Controller
        {
     public ActionResult Test1()
            {
                return this.JsonResult("1");
            }

            [System.Web.Http.Route("t2")]
            public ActionResult Test2()
            {
                return this.JsonResult("2");
            }
    }
```

when I browse to

http://localhost:8080/mvc/MyCtl/Test1

or

http://localhost:8080/mvc/MyCtl/Test2

I get answer

when I browse to

http://localhost:8080/api/MyCtl/t2

I get

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8080/api/MyCtl/t2'.
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'MyCtl'.

in *web.config* I set

```
    <rewrite>
          <rules>

            <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/mvc/" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/index.html" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried it ans still not working :(

Comment: Ohh.your `MyCtlController`  is MVC type controller (inherited from Controller) and you try to access it by using `ApiController` ..you need to create different controller `MyCtlController :ApiController` like this